# Why does multiple cursors use the same char for all cursors with zap-to-char but not with zap-up-to-char?

Tags: interactive, multiple-cursors

This a follow up to my earlier question [Why does multiple-cursors use the same char for all cursors with iy-go-to-char, but not with zap-up-to-char?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9504/why-does-multiple-cursors-use-the-same-char-for-all-cursors-with-iy-go-to-char).

As I describe in that question, for some commands that prompt for a character in the mini-buffer multiple-cursors will repeat the prompting for each cursor, but for others it will happily prompt only once and use that character for all cursors. In particular, for `iy-go-to-char` multiple-cursors prompts only once, but for `zap-up-to-char` it prompts per cursor.

Now, oddly enough for `zap-to-char` the prompting also happens only once, not once per cursor! My question is why does this happen? As far as I can tell the difference is caused by their different calls to interactive:

- `zap-up-to-char` uses the seemingly sensible `(interactive "p\ncZap up to char: ")`,
- `zap-to-char` instead has:

  ```
  (interactive (list (prefix-numeric-value current-prefix-arg)
                     (read-char "Zap to char: " t)))
  ```

That is indeed the cause because taking the implementation of `zap-up-to-char` from `misc.el` and replacing the `interactive` call with one similar to the one `zap-to-char` uses produces a version of `zap-up-to-char` that, when used with multiple-cursors, only prompts once 
(not once per cursor):

```
(defun mc-friendly/zap-up-to-char (arg char)
  (interactive (list (prefix-numeric-value current-prefix-arg)
                     (read-char "Zap up to char: " t)))
  (let ((direction (if (>= arg 0) 1 -1)))
    (kill-region (point)
                 (progn
                   (forward-char direction)
                   (unwind-protect
                       (search-forward (char-to-string char) nil nil arg)
                     (backward-char direction))
           (point)))))
```

Why does changing the call to `interactive` have that effect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because `read-char` is advised to have special behaviour. When running in 'multiple-cursors-mode' it caches the character read the first time. If this cache is full then it does not ask for a character again.

Whatever function is called by "c" in the `interactive` description is not advised in this way.

The implementation is incredibly hackish: for example if you have multiple calls to read-char in the same `interactive` specification you get nonsense. unfortunately I don't see how to improve the situation.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the only real solution to this problem is to remove
the `read-char` special handling and have everything behave worse, but the
same. I'd be happy to see alternative solutions.

Comment: "c" in the `interactive` call seems to directly call the C function `Fread_char` (that's the C primitive underlying the Emacs Lisp function `read-char`).